# How to change the default login account on a NAS Share

Tags: network, login, sharing, nas

I have a Synology NAS which is connecting with the NAS admin account when I log into my Mac. I would like to change the account to a user account. I have tried to disconnect and reconnect with the user account but reverts tot he admin account when I restart my system. How can I change the default login account when connecting to a NAS share via SMB.

Answer (score 2):

Login mounts are stored as startup items, so you need to do the following:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select Users & Groups
3. click on the "Login Items" tab
4. find your NAS login in the list, select it and
   delete it with the '-' button
5. If your NAS admin SW has a method for setting an automount, use that, and ignore the following
6. Mount your NAS volume
7. In the Finder select the mounted volume (or a folder on that volume)
8. Drag the volume icon into the Login Items list (in system preferences)
9. Log out & log back in to test

Comment: Thank you let try this.. Leyland you reference “NAS admin software” would that be on my Mac or Synology how would I determine if I do? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about the Synology NAS admin software. I made an assumption that it set up the admin mount for you in the first place. I would hope that the Synology documentation would help if it indeed had that capability. If not, then steps 6-9 should serve. I didn't mean to be confusing.